# Autoloading class via PSR-0

Tags: php, composer-php

I have the following directory structure

```
oop
 - src
   - FetchTask.php
 - tests
   - FetchTaskTest.php
 - vendor
 - composer.json
 - composer.lock
 - phpunit.xml
```

**// FetchTask.php**

```
<?php 

namespace PHPUnitTuts;

class FetchTask 
{

}
```

**// FetchTaskTest.php**

```
<?php

use PHPUnitTuts\FetchTask;

class Fetch_Test extends AbstractTest
{
    public function setUp() 
    {
        $this->fetch = new FetchTask;
    }

    public function testStoresListOfAssets($value='')
    {
        $this->classHasStaticAttribute('paths', 'FetchTask');
    }
}
```

**// composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "raheel/code",
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.5",
        "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "^4",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { 
            "PHPUnitTuts\\": "src/" 
        }
    },
}
```

**// phpunit.xml**

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="oop">
             <directory>./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

now when i am running `$ vendor/bin/phpunit` it says

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnitTuts\FetchTask' not found in
>   /home/raheel/code/oop/tests/FetchTaskTest.php on line 9

Please advice what i am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Did you run `composer update` after you have changed the composer.json ? Did the Class autload outside a test?

Comment: yes i did but didn't fixed

Comment: Its not working even outside the tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing concepts of [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) and PSR-4.

### To use PSR-0

Move `src/FetchTask.php` to `src/PHPUnitTuts/FetchTask.php`.

### To use PSR-4

Change

```
"psr-0": { 
    "PHPUnitTuts\\": "src/" 
}
```

To

```
"psr-4": { 
    "PHPUnitTuts\\": "src" 
}
```

### Suggested Structure

```
.
├── composer.json
├── phpunit.xml.dist
├── src
│   └── FetchTask.php
└── test
    └── FetchTaskTest.php
```

`composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "raheel/code",
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.5",
        "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "^4",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "PHPUnitTuts\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

`phpunit.xml.dist`

```
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="oop">
             <directory>test</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

`src/FetchTask.php`

```
<?php

namespace PHPUnitTuts;

class FetchTask extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public static $paths = [];
}
```

`test/FetchTaskTest.php`

```
<?php

namespace PHPUnitTuts;

class FetchTaskTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->fetch = new FetchTask();
    }

    public function testStoresListOfAssets()
    {
        $this->assertClassHasStaticAttribute('paths', FetchTask::class);
        // or
        $this->assertClassHasStaticAttribute('paths', get_class($this->fetch));
        // or
        $this->assertClassHasStaticAttribute('paths', 'PHPUnitTuts\\FetchTask');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the declaration for tests is missing, you could place it in the autoload-dev block:

```
{
    "name": "raheel/code",
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.5",
        "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "^4",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { 
            "PHPUnitTuts\\": "src/" 
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-0": { 
            "Tests\\PHPUnitTuts\\": "tests/" 
        }
    },
}
```

And your tests should live in the Tests namespace then.

```
use Tests\PHPUnitTuts\FetchTask
```

For PSR-0 the folder structure must be changed, move the classes in a folder PHPUnitTuts:

```
oop
 - src
   - PHPUnitTuts/FetchTask.php
 - tests
   - PHPUnitTuts/FetchTaskTest.php
 - vendor
 - composer.json
 - composer.lock
 - phpunit.xml
```

Btw, PSR-0 is deprecated, why not use PSR-4?

Comment: psr-4 is working fine ! but i don't understand why not psr-0. Is it completely removed ?

Comment: i updated the answer, i think i forgot that PSR-0 pathes are different